# React.js: Downloading image after applying CSS filters

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web-applications, cloudinary

#### Issue

I'm making an app to edit images and I'm stuck when it is about downloading the images after applying the filters. As expected, the user can drag & drop (or just upload) an image (creating a dynamic URL on Cloudinary) and apply the CSS filters to the uploaded image.

So, basically, I want to save the image into the Cloudinary API, but also applying the filters.

#### ️ Architecture

[Edite web app architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D55t.png) or more about [here](https://github.com/Edite-App/Edite/wiki/%F0%9F%8F%9B%EF%B8%8F-Architecture)

#### ⚙️ Reproduce the issue

You can reproduce this issue by cloning the [Edite GitHub repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D55t.png) and following [the guide](https://github.com/Edite-App/Edite/wiki/%F0%9F%8F%9B%EF%B8%8F-Architecture) to set up the services.

#### Code

**Note:** *see that src is the root*

`components/Toolbar/Right/options.json`

```json
[
  {
    "property": "brightness",
    "value": 100,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "contrast",
    "value": 100,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 200
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "saturate",
    "value": 100,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 200
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "grayscale",
    "value": 0,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "sepia",
    "value": 0,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "invert",
    "value": 0,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100
    },
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "property": "hue-rotate",
    "value": 0,
    "range": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 360
    },
    "unit": "deg"
  }
]
```

`components/FileUploader/index.js`

```js
function FileUploader() {
// Image uploading states
  const dndRef = useRef(); // Access DnD element reference and its current state
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);
  const [uploadedImageUrl, setUploadedImageUrl] = useState('');
  const [src, { blur }] = useProgressiveImg(
    '',
    uploadedImageUrl
  );
  const [uploadedImageName, setUploadedImageName] = useState('image');
  // CSS Filters
  const { activeTool } = useContext(ToolsContext);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
  const selectedFilter = options[activeTool];

  // Get the file's data and send to clodinary
  const onFileChange = async e => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', e.target.files[0]);
    formData.append('upload_preset', 'Edite_App');
    setIsUploading(true);

    let data = await api.post('/image/upload', formData);

    const file = data.data;

    setIsDragging(false);
    setIsUploading(false);
    setUploadedImageUrl(file.secure_url);
    setUploadedImageName(file.original_filename);
  }

   // Get slider value according to the tools
  const handleSliderChange = ({ target }) => {
    setOptions(prevOptions => {
      return prevOptions.map((option, index) => {
        if (index !== activeTool) return option
        return { ...option, value: target.value }
      })
    })
  }

  // Get CSS filters and return as a object
  const handleImageStyling = async () => {
    const filters = options.map(option => {
      return `${option.property}(${option.value}${option.unit})`
    })

    return filters.join(' ');
 I }
}
```

**Note:** To explain better and not just give too much code, you see above that, basically, I get a CSS filters list (JSON file) and also use Cloudinary API to post the data and create a dynamic URL. Although Cloudinary has support for image transformations, I always get stuck on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary won't be able to use the filters in the JSON format, therefore, you will want to map these filters from the JSON file into Cloudinary [image transformations](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_reference). To do that, you will want to create some code/class that handles different input options from your JSON file and converts them to syntax using Cloudinary transformations. E.g. Brightness to [e_brightness](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_reference#e_brightness), Sepia effect to [e_sepia](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_reference#e_sepia) etc.

Once you do that there are two options:

1. If you want the original image on Cloudinary to be the one with the filters applied you will want to use an [incoming transformation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformations_on_upload#incoming_transformations). This is where the requested Cloudinary transformations will be applied on the image ***before*** it's stored in your account. The output image with the transformations applied will be what is stored in your account.
2. The alternative is to upload the original image (untouched) and requesting to generate the transformed versions using [eager transformations](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformations_on_upload#eager_transformations). This would create a situation where the original image does not have any transformations and you would create 'derived' versions with different transformations, which in your case will be the transformations based on the JSON file.

Comment: Thank you, it was a pretty good explanation, but can I still ask something? If you see, once the user uploads the image (making it possible to apply the css filters), it already goes to the Cloudinary storage (without the transformation, ofc). So, it'd be better if I just preview the image using Blob (after uploading locally, not to the storage), then applying the filters with the incoming transformation (sending to the cloud), or... Keep it and just create eager transformations?

Comment: Both are valid use-cases, but I would say that option 2 would be better. With this in Cloudinary, you would have stored as the original the untouched image your user uploaded. This will allow you to create any number of transformations for that original image (referred to as derived images). If you use incoming (option 1), then the transformed image will be stored as the original, not the image the user uploads. At the moment, you may only want to apply a single transformation so both approaches will work, but if you later need to add more transformations then only option 1 would allow that.

Comment: Thank you so much for making it clear. And definitely, the 2nd option now will be the best choice, once the app will have more than just one type of transformations

Comment: You're welcome.
It looks like I had a typo in my comment above. The last line should say "option 2" rather than "option 1".